# Homotopy invariance of line integral on manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider a 1-form: $\omega\in\Gamma(\mathrm{T}^*M)$
and two differentiable curves: $\gamma,\tilde{\gamma}:[a,b]\to M:\gamma(a)=\tilde{\gamma}(a),\gamma(b)=\tilde{\gamma}(b)$
together with a differentiable homotopy: $\Phi:[0,1]\times[a,b]:\Phi(0,t)\equiv\gamma(t),\Phi(1,t)\equiv\tilde{\gamma}(t)$

Prove or disprove the homotopy invariance of the line integral: $\int_\gamma\omega=\int_\tilde{\gamma}\omega$

Note that the homotopy invariance fails for merely continuous functions...

Comment: That doesn't even hold for the constant $f=1$ (the integral just returns the length of the curve)...? Maybe you mean vector valued integrals $\int_\gamma f\,\overrightarrow{ds}$, then it holds for constant functions but not for others.

Comment: Why shouldn't it hold for constant function? Remember: $\int_\gamma f:=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\dot{\gamma}(t)\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: If you use this definition, then it holds for constant functions (I thought you mean $\ldots |\dot{\gamma(t)}| dt$). For nonconstant, the gradient is nonzero and $\int_{\gamma-\tilde{\gamma}} f=\int_{interior} \nabla f$ which is nonzero in general.

Comment: Thx ...can u put this as answer so I can close this question/accept your answer?

Comment: @Freeze_S: Your purported definition of $\int_{\gamma} f$ doesn't seem to make sense: $\gamma'(t)$ is an element of the tangent space to $M$ at $\gamma(t)$. Since the velocities are not elements of a single vector space, it's not clear how you're going to integrate them.

Comment: @user86418: This is shorthand for locally: $\int_\gamma f=\int_\gamma \sum f_idx_i=\int_a^b \gamma^*\sum f_idx_i=\int_a^b \sum f_i\circ\gamma d\gamma_i=\int_a^b \sum f_i\circ\gamma \frac{d\gamma_i}{dt}dt=\int_a^b f\circ\gamma\dot{\gamma}$ together with the canonical identification of tangent spaces on real euclidean space

Comment: @Freeze_S: Something isn't right. If $f_{i}$ stands for a partial derivative, then $\int_{\gamma} \sum f_{i}\, dx_{i} = \int_{\gamma} df$, the integral of a $1$-form over a path. If you really mean to integrate a scalar function over a path, your definition should read $\int_{a}^{b} (f\circ\gamma) |\gamma'(t)|\, dt$ as Peter Franek says. And separately, if you really mean to identify tangent spaces, you're presuming an embedding, on which your integral may depend.

Comment: $f_i$ does not stand for partial derivatives but for the components of the corresponding one form - I should better write $\int_\gamma\omega$ so this becomes $\omega_i$ that was a little bit too sloppy as it is not a scalar function but a one form ...but in any case no modulus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, by the integral, $\int_\gamma f(s(t)) \dot{s}(t) dt$ and everything is in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (otherwise the definition of your integral is not clear), then such invariance can be hardly satisfied by a larger class of functions then constants. For nonconstant $f$, it holds only if $$\int_{\gamma-\tilde{\gamma}} f=0.$$
This means, for any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $$\int_{\gamma-\tilde{\gamma}} (fv)\,\overrightarrow{ds}=0.$$ Assume that $\Omega$ is a $2$-disc bounded by $\gamma-\tilde{\gamma}$. The expression $fv$ can be considered to be a $1$-form and by Stokes theorem, 
$$\int_{\gamma-\tilde{\gamma}} (fv)=\int_{\Omega} d(fv)=0.$$ This should hold for any $\Omega$ and any $v$, so $d(fv)=0$, i.e. $v_i \partial_j f - v_j \partial_i f=0$. Taking for $v$ the basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we get that $\partial_j f=0$ for all $j$, so $f$ is constant.

There must be some simpler explanation, I just don't see it at the moment :(

Comment: (The question changed quite substantially since my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The integral of closed 1-forms is invariant under path-homotopy (Theorem 16.26, Lee SM).

Moreover, the integral over a not necessarily simply connected manifold with boundary of either compactly supported 1-forms with non vanishing non negative exterior derivative or equivalently 1-forms of non vanishing support on the boundary (or sth like that) certainly not invariant under path-homotopy.